# How do I install Jung2 on eclipse?

Tags: java, graph, jung

http://jung.sourceforge.net/

Can someone walk through the steps carefully for me? I have been trying for hours and I can't seem to get it. I'm using a Mac. And, I want to be able to use the Jung2 libraries while programming, using the Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Rohan: JUNG 2.0 Framework contains both binary and source form of jars.

To use the binary jars from JUNG, you need to add them as `Referenced Libraries` in a project. Create a new project. Then, add required JUNG jars somewhere inside project directory. `Refresh` project tree. Right-click on each JUNG jar to add it to `Build Path > Add to Build Path` in Eclipse. By doing this, each will be registered under `Referenced Libraries` tree in the project.

Since a few JUNG jars have source code version, you can open the `Build Path` of the project and go to `Libraries tab`. Under this tab, it lists all JARs. Attach the JUNG source code jar version to equivalent JUNG binary jar version under `Source attachment` of that jar. For example: attach `jung-samples-2.0.1-sources.jar` to `jung-samples-2.0.1.jar`

Once done, go to `jung-samples-2.0.1` under `Referenced Libraries` and open any class in a JUNG package. You will be able to see the source code view of the class.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way is to use maven. You can put jung2 as dependency libraries in your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
        <artifactId>jung2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
        <artifactId>jung-graph-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Now there is a nice maven plugin for eclipse, [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/).

Answer (score 0):

I do not what do you mean by installing? You need to download jung2 lib and libraries, which jung2 depends on colt and generic collections [see download page](http://jung.sourceforge.net/download.html). Next, you need to add these libraries to your classpath, see [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath_jar).