# How can we debug a file which is inside Jar file

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jar

I have a existing  Application , in which some of the code is present 
inside JAr file .
Please tell me how can we debug a file which is inside Jar file ??

I have used JD-GUI , opened that jar and saved all the source
inside my harddisk and attaached this source to the class file from Eclipse .
And When i tried to put breakpoints to that class file , the debugger doesn't stop there .

Please tell me how to deal with this situation ??

Comment: Usually the jar file contains the compiled (.class) files, not the .java source files. Does you jar file have both?

Comment: i have used JD-GUI decompiler to generate the source from that class file and used that .

Comment: What version of eclipse? Also, did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655362/eclipse-displaying-code-source-for-class-file

Answer (score 2):

You try this one:

First open the jar file using JD(Java Decompiler), then click on File -> Save JAR Sources and it will become a .zip file containing the java source files. Then you can add this source zip file in the debug configuration using add source. It will work then for sure.

I also faced the similar issue,sometime while debugging the jar file classes. But after the above procedure the issue got resolved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need source of that jar for this. May be you will get from following link what you want

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-attach-source-in-eclipse-Jar-JDK-debugging.html

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)