# getting started with jung library

Tags: java, graph, jung

Recently i have downloaded the jung library and trying to analyse some datasets.
First of all, is there another tutorial except this: http://www.grotto-networking.com/JUNG/JUNG2-Tutorial.pdf ?

Also, i am working with eclipse and facing difficulties with import of datasets. I don't know if this is a graph question or a java question. Either way, i would like to have some information of how can i work with datasets.

Comment: "Facing difficulties with import of datasets/how can I work with datasets" is not a question.  You need to make it clear what you're trying to do and what specific problem(s) you're running into.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have come across some Basic tutorials about jung.

1.jung [Documentation](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html)

2.sample program using <strike>[jung](http://farhad.arbabzadah.com/2011/09/graph-visualization-with-java-jung/)</strike>

3.How to install jung on [eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616233/how-do-i-install-jung2-on-eclipse)

4.Different kinds of example using [jung](http://jung.sourceforge.net/examples.html).

Comment: I would add that all the examples listed in #4 are available in the distribution.